# CSS Pre-processors: Getting the current value of a css property and changing it

Tags: css, sass, less

Let's say I have following declaration

```css
.foo {
 .grid(1);
}

.grid(@num) {
  width: ... // Some calculated percentage
}
```

Now later I realize that I need `.foo` to be 5% wider is it somehow possible todo `.foo { width: +5%;}` or something similar?

Comment: You won't be able to do anything that CSS can't do. If width was `300px` you could add `5%` to the value and get `315px`, but you can't get `300px + 5%`.

Comment: The only way you could make this work is if you stored the value you want as a variable.

Comment: @zzzzBov the `calc()` function says hi.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

Comment: @cimmanon, While I'm aware that that exists, I'm not willing to use it until it's supported in the browsers that I need to be compatible with. Someday we'll have `calc` and `flexbox` and we'll enter into a golden age of CSS (at least that's how it works in my dreams).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For LESS

In LESS you cannot get at that info so directly. You would need to modify the `.grid` mixin to something like:

```
.grid(@num, @adjust: 0) {
  width: (your regular calaculation) + @adjust; // Some calculated percentage
}
```

By giving it a default of `0`, then you can still just pass `.grid(1)` when you want to, but then if `.foo` needed an adjustment, you do:

```
.foo {
 .grid(1, 5%);
}
```

### For SASS

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe SASS cannot access the property directly either, and would essentially need to do some type of similar solution where the mixin calculation itself is changed.